# Find rows from the same dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to find for every row in my dataframe lists of rows that are similar to the selected row, and then to place these rows potentially into the same dataframe under the related row. Basically, I have power consumption for some moment in time and I want to find matching one from the past based on criteria defined by me. My dataframe header is attached. Is this possible?

```
timestamp     power  daytype  ...  dayofweek weekday  quarter
0 2014-10-15 12:30:00  0.031707  weekday  ...          2       2        4
1 2014-10-15 12:45:00  0.140829  weekday  ...          2       2        4
2 2014-10-15 13:00:00  1.703882  weekday  ...          2       2        4
3 2014-10-15 13:15:00  0.032661  weekday  ...          2       2        4
4 2014-10-15 13:30:00  0.032939  weekday  ...          2       2        4
```

Based on the reply I have got from @brentertainer, I have tried the following:

```
dfNew = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in dfAll.iterrows:
    mask = np.logical_and.reduce([
            dfAll['date']== row['date'],
            dfAll['hour']==row['hour']
            ])
    dfNew.append(dfAll.loc[mask,:])`
```

I would like to have new dataframe appended with these filtered values for every row. Additionally, could I somehow append with an additional column that will contain the index of the row for which the entries are filtered?

Comment: Please qualify exactly what you mean by "similar to the selected row".

Comment: By similar I mean user-specified conditions, i.e. find rows with the same date, same day type and temperature in the range of +-2, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is "yes", but the scenario you describe feels rather abstract. I am providing a similarly abstract example that illustrates some possibilities, and I hope that you will know how it applies to your situation.

Depending on what "similar" constitutes, change the `mask` definition inside the function.

**Create Dummy Data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make example repeatable
np.random.seed(0)

# make dummy data
N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.choice(range(5), size=(N, 8)))
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

**Updated Suggestion:**

```
def similar_rows(idx, row, df):
    mask = np.logical_and.reduce([
        df['a'] == row['a'],
        abs(df['b'] - row['b']) <= 1,
        df['h'] == (3 - row['h'])
    ])
    df_tmp = df.loc[mask, :]
    df_tmp.insert(0, 'original_index', idx)
    return df_tmp

# create result
df_new = pd.concat([similar_rows(idx, row, df) for idx, row in df.iterrows()])
df_new.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_new.rename({'index': 'similar_index'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df_new.head(10))
```

**Result:**

```
   similar_index  original_index  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
0              1               0  4  0  0  4  2  1  0  1
1             88               0  4  1  4  0  0  2  3  1
2              0               1  4  0  3  3  3  1  3  2
3             59               1  4  1  4  1  4  1  2  2
4             82               1  4  0  2  3  4  3  0  2
5              4               2  1  1  1  0  2  4  3  3
6              7               2  1  1  3  3  2  3  0  3
7             37               2  1  0  2  4  4  2  4  3
8             14               3  2  3  1  2  1  4  2  3
9             16               3  2  3  0  4  0  0  2  3
```

---

**Original Suggestion:**

```
# get row at random
row = df.loc[np.random.choice(N), :]
print('Randomly Selected Row:')
print(pd.DataFrame(row).T)

# create and apply a mask for arbitrarily similar rows
mask = np.logical_and.reduce([
    df['a'] == row['a'],
    abs(df['b'] - row['b']) <= 1,
    df['h'] == (3 - row['h'])
])

print('"Similar" Results:')
df_filtered = df.loc[mask, :]
print(df_filtered)
```

**Result:**

```
Randomly Selected Row:
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
23  3  2  4  3  3  0  3  0
"Similar" Results:
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
26  3  2  2  4  3  1  2  3
60  3  1  2  2  4  2  2  3
86  3  2  4  1  3  0  4  3
```

Comment: Due to the limitations in comments, I have clarified further the question based on the answer of @brentertainer.

Comment: @Sanja I have updated my post. If you basing similarity _solely_ on a few strict equalities, there are more efficient ways to go about this. However, if you need it to be flexible (for things like +/-2 range), this will still work.

Comment: Thank you, I encountered the problem with performances, so I will be cautious with this. Thanks again. And yeah, I need it to be flexible.